# Cannot convert from str to int in list (python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, type-conversion

```
def prepare_for_sort(st):
 nums = str(st).split()
 for each in nums:
    each = int(each)
 print(nums)
```

st  is string with number like "20 50 4 8 4 64 6 47 8". Nums must be array of integer. Why this doesnt work?

Comment: `st` seems not to be what you expect it to be, because there's at least no error with `"20 50 4 8 4 64 6 47 8"` as input. Stil doesn't do what you want though

Comment: Even if you were properly making `nums` into a list of ints, you aren't **returning** anything from `prepare_for_sort`, so all your work is for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because your variable `each` is a reference to some object: first, to the same object that's also contained in the list, then, to an integer object. `each` is, however, in no way connected to the list the content of which you want to manipulate.

You could manipulate the list in-place:

```
for index, value in enumerate(nums):
    nums[index] = int(value)
```

Or you can create a new list instead:

```
nums = [int(value) for value in nums]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you currently have it, you are attempting to modify the values in the list from inside of the for loop and this doesn't work because you are simply *re-assigning* the variable `each` within the for loop. The for loop will simply discard this value in order to assign `each` to the next item in the list. Any changes you make to `each` will be discarded as they are completely independent of the `nums` list.

You can actually accomplish your goal with a list comprehension.

```
nums = "20 50 4 8 4 64 6 47 8"
actual_nums = [int(n) for n in nums.split()]
```

Or if you actually want to do this in a loop. You can use indices for the loop so you can actually modify the list in place.

```
for k in range(len(nums)):
    nums[k] = int(nums[k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can in any way avoid it, don't modify the elements of a list while you're looping over it. It will only get you into trouble.
Instead, try this:

```
def prepare_for_sort(st):
    nums = str(st).split()
    new_nums = []
    for each in nums:
        new_nums.append(int(each))
    print(new_nums)
```

Or, even shorter, using a list comprehension:

```
def prepare_for_sort(st):
    nums = str(st).split()
    new_nums = [int(x) for x in nums]
    print(new_nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def prepare_for_sort(st):
    nums = str(st).split()
    arrNums = [int(each) for each in nums]
    return arrNums
```

Of course that you will need to ensure that the string received by the function will always have only integer numbers and spaces.